# Plotting is very slow using ipython console, faster by using canopy (MacOSX 10.8.4)

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, enthought

plotting something as simple as

> > > plot(sin(range(10000)))

in 'ipython --pylab' takes about 15 seconds.

If I plot using the console in canopy, it takes 2-3 seconds.

I tried changing the backend to Qt4Agg, but I see no change in rendering times.

Any idea?

Macbook Air 2010
Canopy Version: 1.0.4.1311

Comment: 1) Does it still take much longer long if you repeat the same plot (i.e. eliminate caching as a factor)?

Comment: 2) Are you running ipython in Canopy User Python? i.e. if from ipython you print sys.prefix, do you see something like '<home>/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User'?